# Encoding Text files with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I built an encryption method that turns plaintext into Hebrew, and I am trying to write the Hebrew to a text file using Python, and I've run across the following issue:

The Hebrew text writes properly in the shell, however once I write it to a text file, this is what is written:

> ää0ä0ãçççâäää0àããåäääãçååãàáÌáÌ0

I am using Python's standard encoding cp1255 to write to my text file. Is there an issue with Python writing to the file, or is it the file itself?

Comment: How are you reading that file to get the crazy characters?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you're using python 3.

Check this out here: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html .

Moreover, you should use UTF-8 to encode your unicode. 
CP1255 has only Hebrew in it https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1255

Your console should support unicode, which is why you see it properly there.

Basically, what I'm saying is: If you use Python 3 and use no shenanigan at all, it *should* work by default :-)

If you force an old encoding... then you'll get down the rabbit hole...